# how to close popup by clicking on iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For any iframe I have, how do I get it to click anywhere in the iframe to close any popups that open from that iframe?

Something like:

```
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="https://somesite.com.br">

</iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#iframe_id').on('click', function(event) { 
        close popups that have opened ...
    });

</script>
```

**NOTE**

I can't use sandbox = "allow-scripts" or other sandbox methods

Comment: You can only close a window by JS if it was opened by JS, how did these popup windows get opened ?

Comment: I have no way of knowing, these are third party websites such as https://verystream.com/e/MxvR81S2se2

Comment: what are those popups? do they have ids? classes?

Comment: I don't know how popups were created, an example iframe I use is with `src = "verystream.com/e/MxvR81S2se2"`

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#iframe_id').on('click', function(event) { 
        //code
    });

</script>
```

if those popups are in `div` then use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#iframe_id').on('click', function(event) { 
        $('#iframe_id').find('div').remove();
    });

</script>
```

though it will remove all div contents if you don't want to include some div contents.

you can just change the `div` to any form of element if that popup have something in common.

Comment: This does not close popups that open when clicking on the iframe. Test with `<iframe id = "iframe_id" src = "https://verystream.com/e/MxvR81S2se2">`